# Bad comportement while check error during makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, doxygen

I want to make automatically the documentation of my project with my makefile.
I also create a target doc (and a variable `DOC_DIRECTORY = ../doc`) to specify the directory of the documentation. In my doxygen file, I added a log file name "doxyLog.log" in the ../doc/ directory.

Here is my target definition :

```
#Creation of the Doxygen documentation
doc: $(DOC_DIRECTORY)/path_finder_doc
    doxygen $(DOC_DIRECTORY)/path_finder_doc
    @echo $(shell test -s ../doc/doxyLog.log; echo $$?)
ifeq ($(shell test -s ../doc/doxyLog.log; echo $$?),1)
    @echo "Generation of the doxygen documentation done"
else
    @echo "Error during the creation of the documentation, please check $(DOC_DIRECTORY)/doxyLog.log"
endif
```

To test if my check is working, I manually introduce an error in my documentation (a bad command like \retufjdkshrn instead of \return). But, when I launch the `make doc`, this error appears after the **second** time :

First make doc (with an error in the doc ) --> Generation of the doxygen documentation done

Second make doc (always the error in the doc) --> Error during the creation of the documentation, please check ../doc/doxyLog.log

I don't understand why, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be two things wrong here, so parts of this answer must be guesswork.

**First:**

```
ifeq ($(shell test -s ../doc/doxyLog.log; echo $$?),1)
    @echo "Generation of the doxygen documentation done"
```

As I understand `test`, it will return `0` if the file exists and `1` if the file does *not* exist. I suspect that you didn't test this before putting it into your makefile.

**Second,** you are confusing *shell* commands with *Make* commands. This:

```
ifeq ($(shell test -s ../doc/doxyLog.log; echo $$?),1)
    @echo "Generation of the doxygen documentation done"
else
    @echo "Error..."
endif
```

is a *Make* conditional. Make will evaluate it before running any rule. Since the log file does not yet exist, the `shell` command will return `1` (see **First**), the conditional will evaluate to true and the entire `if-then-else` statement will become

```
    @echo "Generation of the doxygen documentation done"
```

This will become part of the rule *before the rule is executed*. On the next pass, the file already exists, the `shell` command returns `0` and the the statement becomes

```
    @echo "Error..."
```

This explains why you're getting strange results.

If you want Make to report on the results of the attempt it's just made, you must put a *shell* conditional in a command in the rule:

```
doc: $(DOC_DIRECTORY)/path_finder_doc
    doxygen $(DOC_DIRECTORY)/path_finder_doc
    @if [ -s ../doc/doxyLog.log ]; then echo Log done; else echo error...; fi
```

Comment: Ok, i did not know that we can use a Make conditional. I suppose that -s check if the file is empty?
I used this syntax for the condition because of the example of the Make documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html).

Comment: Hum, to match with my case, if had to check  `@if [! -s ../doc/doxyLog.log ];` , because the file is empty if there is any error. But this is a detail